# What triggers a CustomValidator with a ClientValidationFunction?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, customvalidator

I am using a customValidator to validate whether a date is within a valid range or not within a textbox. It works great if you manually enter in a date and calls my custom ClientValidationFunction. Unfortunately if i use a popup calendar to select a date my customValidator is not triggered.

I was hoping to get a better understanding on how asp:CustomValidators are triggered.

I've tried to force input validation to re-validate when the calendar is closed but have had no luck.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ValidDateCheck" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date." ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate"
    EnableClientScript="True" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="dateboxRJS-validator text-danger" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Javascript

```
clientValidate = function (source, args) {
        console.log("validating...");
        var s       = document.getElementById(source.controltovalidate);
        var minDate = moment("1900-01-01");
        var maxDate = moment().add(200, 'y');
        var inputDate;
        if (moment(s.value, "MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid()) {
            inputDate = moment(s.value, "MM/DD/YYYY");
            console.log(s.value);
            console.log("break");
            if (!inputDate.isBetween(minDate, maxDate)) {
                args.IsValid     = false;
                s.classList.add("is-invalid");
                Page_BlockSubmit = true;
                return false;
            } else {
                s.classList.remove("is-invalid");
                args.IsValid     = true;
                Page_BlockSubmit = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```